# Is there a way to display icons in QListView without text?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Using a QListView, and QStandardItemModel, is it possible to display icons in the list view without displaying the associated text?  QStandardItem is defined as so:

```
QStandardItem ( const QIcon & icon, const QString & text )
```

So it seems to require a text string of some sort - I only want the icon displayed.  If I use the following code, I get the icons as requested, but I also get a blank text element underneath them.  I don't want this.

```
ImageListView->setViewMode( QListView::IconMode );
{
     QStandardItemModel *iStandardModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
     QStandardItem* item1 = new QStandardItem(QIcon("images/shield-280x280.png"),"");
     QStandardItem* item2 = new QStandardItem(QIcon("images/shield-280x280.png"),"");

     iStandardModel->appendRow(item1);
     iStandardModel->appendRow(item2);
     ImageListView->setIconSize(QSize(100,100));
     ImageListView->setUniformItemSizes(true);
     ImageListView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DropOnly);
     ImageListView->setModel(iStandardModel);
}
```

If I go to the trouble of building a custom model, can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do.

first you create a delegate associated with the list-view.Then,

While inserting the elements to the listview, use set-data function to insert the icon and in the paint event of delegate you handle the drawing icon. i hope its clear.

Comment: Code would be nice I concur: custom delegates tend to give people the willies.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the accepted answer, here's the simplest delegate which can optionally hide the text (display role) of items, but otherwise acts like the default delegate. This works with any `QAbstractItemView` subclass (and  `QComboBox`) and any `QAbstractItemModel` subclass as well. And is a better solution if one would rather keep the display role non-null for other views (or whatever reason).

```cpp
class ItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
  public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;

    // simple public member to toggle the display role (create getter/setter if you prefer)
    bool displayRoleEnabled = false;

  protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *o, const QModelIndex &idx) const override
    {
      QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(o, idx);
      // to hide the display role all we need to do is remove the HasDisplay feature
      if (!displayRoleEnabled)
        o->features &= ~QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDisplay;
    }
};
```

Comment: I've gotten a lot of necro-answers to really old questions lately.  I for sure appreciate you taking time to improve things, even if they are dated.

Comment: @ChrisK Yea sorry for the "necro-answer" (is that a thing? :), just that this question pops up petty early in Google results, so I figured I'd maybe help out the next person. Thanks for the +1!